# JSP: Function call inside loop becomes very slow. Help me optimize

Tags: performance, function, jsp, loops

In my JSP, I loop through an object containing a list of employees and display it.
For each employee row, I also provide a link so that the user can view the employee's details. The link calls a Javascript function where the employee ID is passed.

The problem I am having is that the response time dramatically increases with the number of rows in my object.  When my object contains over a thousand records, it takes at least 30 secs to render the page.  Here's the code:

```
function getDetail(empID){

  //AJAX call to get employee details}
}
.
.

<table>
  <c_rt:forEach var="emp" items="${employeeListObj}">
    <tr>
      <td>
    <a href="#" onClick="getDetail('<c:out value="${emp.id}"/>')"><c:out value="${emp.lastName}" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </c_rt:forEach>
</table>
```

I have narrowed down the culprit to the employee ID parameter being dynamic or being evaluated at runtime. I intially thought is it was a JSTL c:out issue, but I also tried changing to an ordinary JSP variable (i.e. getDetail('<%=ctr%>'), and the response time is still slow.

But when I changed it to a static string (i.e. getDetail('some static string')), the response time becomes fine.

I also tried passing it as a function (i.e. onClick="getDetail(function () {return ''})") but response time still didn't improve.

Is there a better (more optimized) way of doing this that will result in a better response time?

Comment: Is the server being slow or the browser being slow?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be showing a thousand records of anything in a single page at all. If you've only defined the axax call once, then all that html is probably what is slowing rendering down. Why not try paging it? Have an ajax call fetch 10 results at a time or something like that?

Comment: @Slaks: Server/DB response time is fine.  I have verified that the slow down is really happening when the employee list page is being rendered.

Comment: But is it on the webserver or the browser?

Comment: @jomanlk: Paging aside. So there's really no way around it? I mean, rendering thousands of anchor tags with javascript calls that have dynamic parameters will really be slow no matter how you optimize it?

Comment: @Slaks: Most probably the browser.

Comment: Try it in Fiddler and see how long it takes to serve the response.  The browser shouldn't care (or know) whether you have a static or dynamic string

Comment: The problem is that you have so much javascript and html for it to render. If you have too many rows it will be too slow. And from a UI point of view, a thousand rows won't be very user friendly either. Have you tried it in different browsers?

Comment: @jomanlk I'm rendering the table inside a fix-sized DIV with a scrollbar, so the whole page itself doesn't scroll when going through the employee list. No, I haven't tried it with different browsers as I only have IE8 installed for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies but I have figured out a simple solution.  Not the most elegant, but it's a simple change and it serves my end user's needs (they dont want pagination, just a scrollable DIV area).

Instead of using this statement inside the loop:

```
<a href="#" onClick="getData('<c:out value="${emp.id}"/>')">
```

I used the employee ID as the ID of the anchor tag and passed that one instead:

```
<a id='<c:out value="${emp.id}"/>' href="#" onClick="getData(this.id)">
```

I don't know why, but the difference was night and day in terms of page rendering time. It now renders for just less than 5 secs compared to over a minute when passing the c:out value directly. I was dealing with 10,000 records btw.

Comment: Interesting, are you using Internet Explorer or something? It's well known to have an extremely poor HTML table renderer. The problem is definitely not in JSP side. Even more, this way it needs to emit more characters than before.

Comment: I'm using IE8. I only have this one installed so I'm not sure if this is not an issue with other browsers (but I'm curious to find out). I know it's not a JSP problem, but the mod edited the title and recategorized my question. Anyway, I'm not sure why there's a big execution/evaluation time difference between an expression inside a Javascript call and one that's not. One would think that they would be evaluated at the same time and should take the same amount of time as well.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser! Did you try reloading the page multiple times with second option? And it always loads in 5 seconds? Could you paste the actual HTML that is being generated in both cases so we can have a look whether it's unusual markup that's causing the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in the browser, you could replace the click handlers with attributes containing the number and a single click handler added through Javascript (eg, jQuery)

**EDIT**: For example:

```
$('table.SomeClass a').click(function() { 
    getDetail($(this).attr('data-employeeId'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with JQuery. Can you show me an example? Thanks a lot!